# Angular filter server side generated select(dropdown)

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I wonder if it is possible to have a `<select>` which `<option>` elements are generated on the server filtered by angularjs with some conditions.

Let's assume the following scenario. We have two `<select>` elements.

```
<select id="parent">
    <option>Parent option 1</option>
    <option>Parent option 2</option>
    ...
    <option>Parent option 2000</option>
</select>

<select id="child">
    <option>Parent option 1 Child 1</option>
    <option>Parent option 1 Child 2</option>
    ...
    <option>Parent option 1 Child 1000</option>

    <option>Parent option 2 Child 1</option>
    <option>Parent option 2 Child 2</option>
    ...
    <option>Parent option 2 Child 1000</option>

    ......

    <option>Parent option 2000 Child 1</option>
    <option>Parent option 2000 Child 2</option>
    ...
    <option>Parent option 2000 Child 1000</option>
</select>
```

So when parent option is selected then filter the child `<select>`.

Should I make a routine to read all the options to an arrays in the javascript?

Or should I make ajax calls to the server to obtain the data as json and then populate it(this I saw is the traditional way of doing the trick and then the HTML of the selects is generated on client side)?

I would like to keep HTML been generated on the server side.
BTW server is Apache and I use PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: Of course it's possible, there is pretty much nothing different from how you would do it common angular way. Just bind select to model and initialize it properly. There is no need to have ngRepeat if you want to render options server-side

Comment: I will definitely try this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that a problem with generating this server-side is after you have selected an option in the parent (which filters the child options), and then select another option in paren, you need to keep track of what options were there to begin with.

I would suggest providing angular with the options for both `<select>`.

If angular has the list of options and they are structured something like this, the filtering would be trivial.

```
...
function controller() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.parentValue = null;
  vm.childValue = null;

  vm.parentOptions = [
    {key: 'parent 1', value: 1},
    {key: 'parent 2', value: 2},
  ];
  vm.childOptions = [
    {key: 'parent 1 child 1', value: 'parent1_child1', category: 1},
    {key: 'parent 1 child 2', value: 'parent1_child1', category: 1},
    {key: 'parent 2 child 1', value: 'parent2_child1', category: 2},
    {key: 'parent 2 child 2', value: 'parent2_child2', category: 2},
  ];
}
...
```

---

```
<html>
...
<div ng-controller="controller as ctrl">
  <select ng-model="ctrl.parentValue"
          ng-options="parent.key as parent.value for parent in ctrl.parentOptions">
  </select>
  <select ng-model="ctrl.childValue" 
          ng-options="child.key as child.value for child in ctrl.childOptions | filter:{category: ctrl.parentValue}">
  </select>
</div>
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use AngularJS to generate HTML on the client side, and get the JSON data from the server.

### Trigger action on parent select change

```
<select id="parent" ng-model="parentSelectValue" ng-change="filterChildSelect(parentSelectValue)">
    <option value="parentValue1">Parent option 1</option>
    <option value="parentValue2">Parent option 2</option>
    <!-- ... -->
    <option value="parentValue2000">Parent option 2000</option>
</select>
```

This will trigger `filterChildSelect(parentSelectValue)` on your controller when the value selected changes.

### Populate child select with server data

In your controller define the variable with your JSON data. For the sake of simplicity I will define an static array, but this should be the JSON data from your server

```
$scope.childDataOriginal = [
    {
        name: "Child name 1",
        value: "child1"
    }, {
        name: "Child name 2",
        value: "child2"
    }
];
// Iterave over a copy of the original data in order not to modify it when filtering
$scope.childData = angular.copy($scope.childDataOriginal);
```

Then iterave over it in your view:

```
<select id="child">
    <option ng-repeat="child in childData" value="{{child.value}}">{{child.name}}</option>
</select>
```

### Define your filtering function in your controller

Define a function which iterates over your original data and pushes to a temprary array the elements which pass some filter. Then assign that temprary array to your `$scope.childData` array.

```
$scope.filterChildSelect = function (parentSelectedValue) {
    var i,
        childDataTmp = []

    for (i = 0; i < $scope.childDataOriginal.length; i = i + 1) {
        if (someCondition) {
            childDataTmp.push($scope.childDataOriginal[i]);
        }
    }

    $scope.childData = childDataTmp;
}
```

Comment: *"I highly recommend you to use AngularJS to generate HTML on the client side, and get the JSON data from the server."* - I would say, if you can prerender HTML like OP is doing, it's way better then what you recommend.